# Replaced hypen by â€“ in html text

Tags: html

why hypen is replaced  by â€“ in html text

```
               <div class="left">Additional website – URL</div>
```

But when loading webpage shows as ' Additional website â€“ URL ' .

I know use of Html code instead of this hypen ,but I want to know how it happens because just above  div tag is working correctly

```
             <div class="left">Additional website - Name</div>
```

Webpage as 'Additional website - Name'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into encoding issues. Using a correct header for your site may have an effect on how it is rendered. Could you post your headers?

Comment: <meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" http-equiv="Content-Type"><link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico"><link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico">

Comment: It seems that you have in your first example used and en or em-dash and in your second code block a hyphen? Also try using html entities. &ndash; for en-dash. &mdash; etc.

Comment: "charset=UTF-8" may work sufficiently depending on your application

Answer (score 2):

What you see is an en-dash (not a hyphen!) which is correctly encoded in UTF-8 in the HTML file, but decoded incorrectly by the browser. You must set your browser’s character encoding to UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

it happened to me with the '–' character (long minus sign).
I used this simple replace so resolve it:

```
htmlText = htmlText.Replace('–', '-');
```

Comment: No need to replace it. Change character set to be encoded in UTF-8.